# Ruby Net::HTTP patch request get 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http, bad-gateway

I am trying to implement a Curl patch request by Ruby. The Curl request is something like below:

```
curl https://mywebsite/test/plan \
-X PATCH \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {myJWT}' \
-d '{
  "CheckOrNot": "N",
  "CheckList": [
      {
        "id": "123"
      },
      {
        "id": "234"
      }
   ]
}'
```

When I run the Curl command, I could get:

> 400 Bad Request.

But when I try to use Ruby to make the request like below:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://mywebsite/test/plan")
request = Net::HTTP::Patch.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request["Authorization"] = "Bearer {myJWT}"
request.body = JSON.dump({
    "CheckOrNot" => "N",
    "plans" => [
    {
        "id" => "123"
    },
    {
        "id" => "234"
    }
  ]
})


req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https", 
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
   http.request(request)
end
```

I will always get a

> 502 Bad Gateway: an invalid response was received from the upstream server\n.

Could anyone explain why this happened? How could I fix it? And is there a better way to implement a Curl Patch requirement in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the IP address I called from the Curl and net/HTTP client is different. Use the new client curb and successfully use the API.